# division of work in openmp do

Tags: fortran, openmp

If for example I have the following do loop

```
!$OMP DO PRIVATE(i,j,k,l,...) DEFAULT(SHARED)
do i=1,length
   ...
   do j=k,l
   ...
   end do
end do
!$OMP END DO
```

Will the division of the work between threads be "length/numberofthreads"? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default schedule is implementation dependent. see: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/

If you want to control it use `SCHEDULE(x)` where x is one of `STATIC`, `DYNAMIC`, `GUIDED`, `RUNTIME`, `AUTO`. See the link for descriptions.

Comment: in any case the inner do-loop is going to be private per thread, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, unless you use the new `COLLAPSE`, but I have never used it and don't know it well.

Comment: How would collapse help in this case? I am asking this because my j,k,l are private? Or is there anything I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by help? I don't know what you want to achieve. What `collapse` does you can find here http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/compbg/v121v141/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc%2Fproguide%2Fcollapseclause.html

Comment: The loop indexes have to be private in any case!

Comment: I understand the indices (i.e. i and j) but in above case the bounds of inner do-loop are also private. So do you think it would still help or not? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where the values of the bounds come from, it is not at all clear from your code, but more importantly, I don't know what you mean by HELP because you did not present any problem you solve to us. Your original question seems to be about something I already answered.

Comment: I haven't used OpenMP in Fortran, but in C collapse only works if the compiler can statically combine the loops. i.e. if you couldn't write the code as one big loop, then collapse won't work.

Comment: @pburka I probably shouldn't have mentioned collapse at all. You are right, but we don't know if they are not constant. But then they shouldn't be private. Anyway, tho code is not nearly enough.